# How to change color of the burger icon using iconStyleLeft or some other metthod?

Tags: reactjs, material-ui

I tried to change the color of the default burger icon present in the left using iconStyleLeft but the color remains unchanged.

```
import React from 'react';
import AppBar from 'material-ui/AppBar';
import {grey50, grey900 } from 'material-ui/styles/colors';


const NavBar = () => (
    <div>
    <AppBar
      title="Home-pro"
      titleStyle ={{color: grey900, textAlign: 'center'}}
      style={{backgroundColor: grey50}}
      iconStyleLeft={{color: grey900}}


    />
    </div>
  );

  export default NavBar;
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This style `iconStyleLeft={{color: grey900}}` is applied to leftside `div` element, not on svgIcon, that is why color remain unchanged. You can use either `iconClassNameLeft` or add custom icon with any coloring using `iconElementLeft`.

You can check example here: [AppBar Example with custom icons](https://codesandbox.io/s/p502r97w1j)

Comment: I tried using custom class by importing css file `conClassNameLeft="burgerClass"` with css code `.burgerClass {
    color: black; 
 }` but that didnt work ! Finally i used `iconElementLeft={<IconButton><NavigationClose /></IconButton>}
    />` but using IconButton throws an error so removed the tags (I had imported them before) and it started working. Thank you My Fix: `iconElementLeft={<ActionReorder style={iconStyles}/>}`

Comment: `iconClassNameLeft` didn't work for you, because you need to write css like  thar `.burgerClass svg {color: red}` . Accept the answer if it was helpful to you, cheers!